# How to store Checkboxes in Parse.com

Tags: jquery, parse-platform

I have built a site where there is a list of movies. A user can log in and keep track of how many movies they've seen by checking a box in a table.

Edit: Here's the code in question (html and script toward bottom). As of now, I can store the checklist values in an object on parse, but cannot figure out how to get the getChecklist function to retrieve and display the object of values back onto the checkboxes. gist.github.com/ripplep/765aa712a7feced2b5bf

I'm using JQuery and [Parse](http://www.parse.com).

Here's the key parts of the script where the getChecklist function needs to be completed and where I am drawing a blank. Storing a newChecklist on submit seems to be working and stores the checklist id along with a boolean.

EDIT: Right now, the console logs-  Checklist:[object Object]

```
        var Checklist = Parse.Object.extend("Checklist");

        //get checkboxes from parse and load them onto screen
        function getChecklist() {
            var query = new Parse.Query(Checklist);
            query.find({
                success: function(results){
                    var output = {};

                    for (var i in results) {
                        var check = results[i].get("check");
                        console.log("Checklist:"+check);
                        //??????
                        output += {}
                        //??????
                    }
                }, error: function(error){
                        console.log("Query Error:"+error.message);
                }
            });
        }

        getChecklist();

        //on submit, the checklist values are stored in parse
        $("#movieList").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            var checkboxValues = {};
            $(":checkbox").each(function(){
                checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
            });

            var newChecklist = new Checklist(); 
            newChecklist.set("check", checkboxValues);

            newChecklist.save({
                success: function(){

                }, error: function(error){
                    console.log("Error:"+error.message);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: When you say 'struggling' can you be more specific? Is there code you've tried that is behaving unexpectedly? Refer to http://www.sscce.org for how to construct a great question in this domain!

Comment: hey, sorry for the ambiguity. here's the code in question (html and script toward bottom). As of now, I can store the checklist values in an object on parse, but cannot figure out how to get the getChecklist function to retrieve and display the object of values back onto the checkboxes. https://gist.github.com/ripplep/765aa712a7feced2b5bf

Comment: You should include the critical parts in your question, rather than just linking to a github: the github link is useful if more context is needed, but S.O. tries to avoid link-rot, and one way to do that is to include the key parts here.

Comment: Okeydoke! Edited the original question to include key parts of code. Thanks for being patient. It's probably very obvious that I'm just starting out :)

Comment: Are you seeing output on your `console.log` indicating whether there is anything in your `results` parameter?

Comment: The console logs-- Checklist:[object Object]

Comment: Do you know how to set a breakpoint in Developer Tools and inspect the contents of that object?

Comment: No... Sorry. In parse the object is stored as follows: {"c1":false,"c2":true,"c3":true}

Comment: What the console is telling you is that `check` is a complex object. I highly recommend learning the devtools (it comes standard in Chrome) as they would be incredibly helpful here to surface the part of the variable you want: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: It's a bit frustrating because I ask beginner questions and am asked to look at resources but don't know necessarily what to look for, or how it can help me with my problem.